# Count of a data type in a file in C++

Tags: c++

I have a file with strings and integers. For example, this is how my file is

```
string int int string int int
```

How do I get the count of only strings in the file? I thought of writing the `count` in the beginning of the file. But the count was not proper while reading.

Comment: what have you tired so far??? Please put here

Answer (score 0):

If it is a text file, you can easily read the "words" from the file and then determine if they are numbers or not using `atoi`, `atol`, `atoll`, `atoq`. And when you got an answer (ie: this is a number, or not), just increment a variable :)

Comment: `atoi` etc. will _not_ tell you if they are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string word;
while (std::cin >> word)
{
    std::istringstream iss(word);
    int my_int;
    char garbage;
    num_ints += (iss >> my_int) && !(iss >> garbage);
    ++num_words;
}
num_strings = num_words - num_ints;
```

Comment: What's the role of `iss >> garbage`?  If `iss >> my_int` succeeds, it won't be evaluated, and if `iss >> my_int` fails, `iss` is in a failed state, and all further input will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Parse through each item. For each item compare the ascii values of the characters in it.If it is between 48 and 57(inclusive) , it is an int. Otherwise it is a string.

Comment: `-1` is not an `int`?  (And who says that the characters are ASCII.  Using `isdigit` would be a far better idea.)